# Why can't I access this other class's method?

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, syntax-error, text-files

I'm trying to access this other class's method in order to get the average from a grade book of students. I get "illegal start of expression" and "';' expected" errors. Can someone tell me why?

```
     public double getClassAverage{
        double a = 0.0;
        for(Student s : Gradebook.java){
           a+=s.numericScore();
        }
        return a / 17;
     }
```

Here's the sample gradebook:

```
Ozzy:Osbourne:666666666:64:100:90:80:70:60:50:40:30:75:50:40:20:50
Paris:Hilton:234456789:32:100:100:60:50:75:40:90:100:75:80:90:85:90
Honey:Booboo:112117654:7:20:15:0:0:40:0:50:30:50:25:40:20:20
Bilbo:Baggins:481516234:50:100:100:80:80:60:90:100:100:80:75:90:85:80
Bill:Gates:642767638:57:100:100:100:100:100:100:100:100:100:100:100:100:100
```

That's not the grade book class, this is the gradebook class:

public class Gradebook
   {

```
  // maximum number of students per class
  private static final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS = 30;

  // array of students in the gradebook    
    private Student [] students;

    // index (into students array) 
    // where we should insert next student
    private int currentStudentIndex;

  // constructor with Student array
  public Gradebook(Student [] students)
  {
       int i;
       this.students = new Student[MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS]; 
     for (i = 0; i < students.length && i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS; i++)
        {
           this.students[i] = students[i]; 
        }
        this.currentStudentIndex = i;
  }

  // no-arg constructor   
  public Gradebook()
  {
     // allocate enough space for the max number of students
     this.students = new Student[MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS]; 
        this.currentStudentIndex = 0;  
  }

  public void addStudent(Student s)
    {
        if (currentStudentIndex >= MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS)
        {
            // too many students: do not add...print an error and return
            System.out.println("Could not add " + s.getName() + "...class is full");
            return; 
        }

        this.students[currentStudentIndex] = s;
        currentStudentIndex++;
    }

    public int getNumberOfStudentsInGradebook()
    {
        return currentStudentIndex;
    }

    public Student getStudent(int index)
    {
        return students[index];
    }
   }
```

I want to take each student from the sample gradebook and get the average of their grades. I have a separate file that I don't want to post because I think it will be too much code, where the getClassAverage is. In fact, I'm probably going to lose points for what I have right now. Lol

Comment: You don't access other classes (or objects of other classes) based on which file they were compiled from. This should be covered in the first or second chapter in any java book or online tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Gradebook.java is not an Object, but a file, presumably one that contains a class called Gradebook.  Even assuming that the Gradebook class implementing something that can be used in a for loop, it's still not an object and accessing it static will not work.

You probably need at least a `new Gradebook()` somewhere, probably also a method like `getStudents()`.

You want to access a Collection of Student objects, obviously. To do so, there must be either a static collection of those objects inside the Gradebook class - then you would need to call something like Gradebook.students or Gradebook.getStudents(). Or there must be a collection of those objects inside an Object of type Gradebook. In this case, you would need such an object, let's call it aGradebook here, and call something like aGradebook.students() or aGradebook.getStudents() - in these cases, the member or methods wouldn't be static.

Comment: I'm trying to access a file. I'm trying to access a class within a file.

Comment: You can access a file but all you get will be text. And you can't do this way. In java you are working with Objects, sometimes static methods and members, but neither is in this code.

Comment: @GaryTheurpe: It's not really clear what you mean. What are you expecting the expression `Gradebook.java` to evalute to?

Comment: I have a sample gradebook that I'll post so it makes more sense